# How to have a parent property in C# class?

Tags: c#, properties, parent

For example, in the following classes I need to have a `Parent` property in `Cupboard` and `Shelf`. How do I do it?

```
public class Room
{
    public List<Cupboard> Cupboards { get; set; }
}

public class Cupboard
{
    public Room Parent 
    {
        get
        {

        }
    }
    public List<Shelf> Shelves { get; set; }
}

public class Shelf
{

}
```

Comment: This isn't really related to your question, but whenever I see a `List<T>` property with a public setter it makes me very skeptical. That's almost never a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an automatically implemented property:

```
public class Cupboard
{
    public Room Parent { get; set; }
}
```

You can also choose to make the setter private and set it in the constructor.

```
public class Cupboard
{
    public Cupboard(Room parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }

    public Room Parent { get; private set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
Room room = new Room();
Cupboard cupboard = new Cupboard(room);
Console.WriteLine(cupboard.Parent.ToString());
```

If you have many objects that all have a parent room you might want to create an interface so that you can find out which room is an object's parent without having to know its specific type.

```
interface IRoomObject
{
    Room { get; }
}

public class Cupboard : IRoomObject
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I tried the first two methods you mentioned, it still shows null for Parent.

It is actually a WCF service and I'm populating the fields from xml data using LINQ

Comment: @gangt: I've added some code to show one way you could use the second example.

Comment: here is the LINQ

            var rooms = (from room in UIDocument.Descendants("rooms")
                         select new Room
                         {
                             Cupboards = UIDocument.Descendants("cupboards").Where(frame => frame.Element("roomdid").Value == room.Element("roomid").Value).Select(cupboard => new Cupboard
                             {

                             }).ToList()
                         });

Comment: in the LINQ, I couldn't figure out how to set the Parent property.

Comment: @gangt: Of course you couldn't figure it out how to set the Parent property - the room doesn't even *exist* yet at the point where you are creating the Cupboards. You probably shouldn't even be doing this with LINQ - it's not really the right tool for the job. If you insist on using LINQ then try running this code afterwards to run through your list setting all the Parent properties: `foreach (Room room in rooms) { foreach (Cupboard cupboard in room.Cupboards) { cupboard.Parent = room; }}`

Comment: Perfect, that works. But I'm wondering, will that affect the performance. Thanks.